# Bootstrap modal not displayed over another modal

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-5

I have a modal thats being created when "Click me here" button is clicked, Further the modal needs to show a toast modal conveying some Thank you message.

The thank you modal closes the existing modal when save is clicked. The expected was, when save is clicked the save modal should not be unloaded, the thank you modal should be kept loaded over the top of save modal.

When save is clicked I get the error message

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'backdrop')
```

[image]

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <button id="clickme">Click me here</button>
  
<ul class="list-group task-point">
</ul>

  <script>
  
        function showToast(m,title="Error") {
            $("#modal")
                .html(`<div class="modal fade" id="messagemodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="messagemodal" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-sm modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="p-2 modal-header">
                    <h5 class="ms-2 modal-title">${title}</h5>
            <button type="button" class="me-1 btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="text-start modal-body">
                    ${m}<br/><br/>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>`);
            var modal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('messagemodal'), {
                keyboard: false
            });
            modal.show();
        }
        
        
    $("#clickme").click(function (event) {
    
    var code = $(".dropdown-menu").length+1
    
      $(".task-point").append(`
            <li class="list-group-item">
                <img src="https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/networking-manager.png" class="float-start" />            

                <div class="btn-group float-end">
                    <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" data-bs-display="static" aria-expanded="false"> Action </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-lg-end">
                        <li><a data-bs-toggle="modal" href="#exampleModalToggle-${code}" role="button" class="dropdown-item" href="#">Edit ${code}</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Delete ${code}</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Run ${code}</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                
    <div class="ms-5">This is ${code} item<br/>
    <small class="text-secondary">This is a ${code} item description</small>
    <div>
                <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalToggle-${code}" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="exampleModalToggleLabel" tabindex="-1">
                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-fullscreen">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalToggleLabel">Create a file</h1>
                                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body"> What is Lorem Ipsum? </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-target="#exampleModalToggle2" data-bs-toggle="modal" onclick="showToast('Thanks for saving');">Save</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        `);
        $(`#exampleModalToggle-${$(".dropdown-menu").length}`).modal("show")
    })
    

  </script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below code and replace it with your code:

```html
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
    <style>
.modal-backdrop.fade.show + .modal-backdrop.show {
z-index: 9999;
}

div#messagemodal {
z-index: 99999;
}

</style>
      <button id="clickme">Click me here</button>
      
    <ul class="list-group task-point">
    </ul>
    
        <div id="modal">
        </div>  
      <script>
      
            function showToast(m,title="Error") {
                $("#modal")
                    .html(`<div class="modal fade" id="messagemodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="messagemodal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                      <div class="p-2 modal-header">
                        <h5 class="ms-2 modal-title">${title}</h5>
                <button type="button" class="me-1 btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                      </div>
                      <div class="text-start modal-body">
                        ${m}<br/><br/>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>`);
               
                
                $("#messagemodal").modal('show');
                
                $(document).on("click", ".me-1", function() { $("#messagemodal").modal('hide');  $("#modal").empty();});
            }
            
            
            
        $("#clickme").click(function (event) {
        
        var code = $(".dropdown-menu").length+1
        
          $(".task-point").append(`
                <li class="list-group-item">
                    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/networking-manager.png" class="float-start" />            
    
                    <div class="btn-group float-end">
                        <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" data-bs-display="static" aria-expanded="false"> Action </button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-lg-end">
                            <li><a data-bs-toggle="modal" href="#exampleModalToggle-${code}" role="button" class="dropdown-item" href="#">Edit ${code}</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Delete ${code}</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Run ${code}</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    
        <div class="ms-5">This is ${code} item<br/>
        <small class="text-secondary">This is a ${code} item description</small>
        <div>
                    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalToggle-${code}" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="exampleModalToggleLabel" tabindex="-1" da>
                        <div class="modal-dialog modal-fullscreen">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalToggleLabel">Create a file</h1>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body"> What is Lorem Ipsum? </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="showToast('Thanks for saving');">Save</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            `);
            $(`#exampleModalToggle-${$(".dropdown-menu").length}`).modal("show");
        })
        
    
      </script>
    
    </body>
```

For Thank you popup faded backdrop, put below css in the style sheet

```
.modal-backdrop.fade.show + .modal-backdrop.show {
    z-index: 9999;
}

div#messagemodal {
    z-index: 99999;
}
```

If above css is not working for you then please use parent class name along with the css.